# Как получить без цикла сумму списка атрибутов полученного из JSON?

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Можно ли получить сумму списка атрибутов полученного из JSON без цикла?

Пробую `SUM` с функцией `JSON_QUERY`:

```
DECLARE 
    data varchar2(200);
    json varchar2 (4000) := '
        {"Implement_Details": [
        {
          "Hours": "100",
          "Implement1": "Laser Leveler"
        },
        {
          "Hours": "400",
          "Implement1": "Trolley"
        },
        {
          "Hours": "100",
          "Implement1": "Cultivator"
        }
      ]}';
BEGIN 
    SELECT SUM(JSON_QUERY(json, '$.Implement_Details[*].Hours' WITH ARRAY WRAPPER)) INTO data
    FROM dual;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(data);
END;
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> Error report -
> ORA-01722: invalid number

Ожидаемый результат: `100 + 400 + 100 = 600`

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Can We get sum of list attributes in oracle without loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62493980) от участника [@NIKHIL KULSHRESTHA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8447289/nikhil-kulshrestha)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62493980

Answer (score 3):

Функция `SUM()` ожидает значения в табличной форме, а [JSON_QUERY](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/function-JSON_QUERY.html#GUID-D64C7BE9-335D-449C-916D-1123539BF1FB) возвращает список атрибутов как список JSON, то есть, строку `[100, 400, 100]`.

Надо воспользоваться [JSON_TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/function-JSON_TABLE.html#GUID-0172660F-CE29-4765-BF2C-C405BDE8369A). Как то так:

```
var rc refcursor
declare 
    doc varchar2 (4000) := '
        {"Implement_Details": [
            {"Hours": "100", "Implement1": "Laser Leveler"}, 
            {"Hours": "400", "Implement1": "Trolley"},
            {"Hours": "100", "Implement1": "Cultivator"}
        ]}';
begin 
    open :rc for 
        select sum (val) sum
        from json_table (doc, '$.Implement_Details[*].Hours'
            columns (val int path '$'));
end;
/

       SUM
----------
       600
```

---